# oData Query Times out on Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on building an oData endpoint (using WebAPI 2) for a SQL server 2014 DB. One of those tables contains ~10 million records, and the table is mostly static (data gets added annually). I built up the basic endpoint and it just times out. Even when I try adding a top=2 to the query (in case the problem was too large of a dataset being retrieved) the same behavior happens.

I know that oData is capable of handling very large tables, but I haven't found anything that helps me with this.

Any advice for how to fix this up? Feel free to ask any clarifying questions.

Nick

Comment: Have you looked at adding some table indexes?

Comment: The Primary and foreign keys are all indexed. Since the table is mostly static could (should?) I just index every column? I'm not concerned about insert speeds at all since it is very rare.

Comment: Have you examined the query executed on the server (for example with SQL Server Profiler)?